# Como extrair um texto de uma página?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

Estou criando um programa de web scraping e gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de extrair o texto de um site dessa maneira:

Esse é o html:

````
<div class="s-sidebarwidget s-sidebarwidget__yellow s-anchors s-anchors__default sidebar-help" id="how-to-format" style="">

    <h4 class="s-sidebarwidget--header mb0">
        Como formatar
            <a href="#wmd-input" class="js-back-to-edit-field s-sidebarwidget--action d-none md:d-inline">back <svg aria-hidden="true" class="svg-icon va-middle iconArrowUpSm" width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 14 14"><path d="M3 9h8L7 5z"></path></svg></a>
    </h4>
    <div class="s-sidebarwidget--content d-block">


        <p>
            <span class="dingus">►</span> create code fences with backticks ` or tildes ~
            </p><div class="bg-black-050 p8 bar-sm ff-mono my4 wmx2">
                ```<br>
                like so<br>
                ```
            </div>
        <p></p>
        <p>
            <span class="dingus">►</span> add language identifier to highlight code
            </p><div class="bg-black-050 p8 bar-sm ff-mono my4 wmx2">
                ```python<br>
                <span class="fc-blue-600">def</span> function(foo):<br>
                <span class="fc-blue-600">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;print</span>(foo)<br>
                ```
            </div>
        <p></p>
        <p><span class="dingus">►</span> coloque retornos entre os parágrafos</p>
        <p><span class="dingus">►</span> para quebra de linha adicione 2 espaços no final</p>
        <p><span class="dingus">►</span> <i>_itálico_</i> ou <b>**negrito**</b></p>
            <p><span class="dingus">►</span> recue o código em 4 espaços</p>
    <p><span class="dingus">►</span> escapes de acentos graves <code>`parecido _portanto_`</code></p>

        <p><span class="dingus">►</span> destaque colocando &gt; no início da linha</p>
        <p><span class="dingus">►</span> para fazer links</p>
        <p>&lt;http://foo.com&gt;<br>[foo](http://foo.com)<br>&lt;a href="http://foo.com"&gt;foo&lt;/a&gt;</p>

        <p class="ar">
            <a href="/editing-help" target="_edithelp">ajuda na formatação »</a><br>
                        <a href="/questions/how-to-ask">ajuda para perguntas »</a>

        </p>

    </div>
</div>
````

Isso é o que eu vejo (o que eu quero extrair):

````
     Como formatar

► create code fences with backticks ` or tildes ~
```
like so
```

► add language identifier to highlight code
```python
def function(foo):
    print(foo)
```

► coloque retornos entre os parágrafos

► para quebra de linha adicione 2 espaços no final

► _itálico_ ou **negrito**

► recue o código em 4 espaços

► escapes de acentos graves `parecido _portanto_`

► destaque colocando > no início da linha

► para fazer links

<http://foo.com>
[foo](http://foo.com)
<a href="http://foo.com">foo</a>
````

Basicamente, gostaria de extrair o texto de um site como se eu tivesse apertado ctrl + a, ctrl + c.

Ja tentei fazer dessa maneira, porém não saiu como esperado: `BeautifulSoup(req, 'html.parser').get_text`

Existe alguma maneira de transformar o html em "texto"?

Comment: Existem algumas maneiras de fazer isso sim. Você pode usar [Regex](https://regexone.com/references/python) ou [CGI](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html) sendo que esse último é o melhor para lidar com HTML/páginas web.

Comment: Sua pergunta é muito vaga sobre o quão longe você já foi? Mas se você estiver começando do zero você vai precisar simular uma requisição com algum http request, pra parsear o conteúdo você poderia por exemplo usar o beautifulsoup, mas existem mil maneiras, como eu disse antes, sua pergunta é muito vaga

Comment: Eu ja tentei usando bs4 e requests, porém ainda não consegui transformar html em texto (igual ao meu exemplo)

Comment: Edite a sua pergunta, e coloque o seu código Python, para que possamos te mostrar onde está o problema, e te ajudar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri uma maneira de fazer isso usando o módulo
[html2text](https://pypi.org/project/html2text/)

```
import requests
import html2text
req = requests.get('https://pastebin.com/').text
print(html2text.html2text(req))
```

Comment: Falta explicar como instala o módulo, pq a sua resposta pode ser util a futuros visitantes

Answer (score 1):

Supondo que esteja usando o bs4 poderia usar o método prório `getText` (https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("<ul><li>foo</li><li>bar</li><li>baz</li>", 'html.parser')

print(soup.get_text('\n'))
```

O `\n` vai ser o delimitador entre as tags removidas

Ou usar o `.strings` (https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings) para pegar em um vetor:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("<ul><li>foo</li><li>bar</li><li>baz</li>", 'html.parser')

for string in soup.strings:
    print(repr(string))
```